# Xcode 13: `Value of type 'NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions' has no member 'databaseScope'`

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcode13

After upgrading to Xcode 13.0 (13A233), the following code that used to work with Xcode 12

```swift
let publicOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: containerIdentifier)
publicOptions.databaseScope = .public
```

produces the error: `Value of type 'NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions' has no member 'databaseScope'`

And indeed when I click on `NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions` it shows the old (iOS 13) version of `CoreData` framework without `databaseScope`.

My deployment target is iOS 14 and it used to work with Xcode 12 for a long long time. Also, it is now broken in several projects, including the ones that were created with Xcode 12, i.e. rather recently.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently, now it is required to `import CloudKit` as well to make `databaseScope` available in `CoreData`'s `NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions` class.

Comment: damn I looked for hours to find your comment and solution -.-